# String concate issues in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am creating username from first and last name. It was working fine with swift 2.2 but after migrating to swift 3 now the string do get concate but when it does the first name is have optional with it. Check below images
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: user firstName!

Comment: `let name = "\(firstName) \(lastName)"!`

Comment: @Parth, Could you please paste the code so we can play with it in ground? :)

Comment: @Scriptable : Playground is not accepting your syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like this

```
let name = "\(firstName!) \(lastName)"
```

I have tried with basic example too. If string contain **optional("")** then you can resolve it by this by force the compiler to implicitly force unwrap.

you can check in .playground

```
let firstname : String!
let lastname : String!
firstname = "Hello" ==> "Hello"
lastname = "World" ==> "World"

let fullname = "\(firstname) \(lastname)" ==> "Optional("Hello") Optional("World")"

let fullname = "\(firstname!) \(lastname!)" ==> "Hello World"
```

Give it a try using above solution, Hope it Helps!

Comment: firstName is already implicit unwrapped String, so why this is needed?

Comment: Yes that's correct it gets fixed by it but even if i don't add the type remains String!.

Comment: @BaSha If firstname is already implicit, then it will show the correct value right ? yet if it is not, then you have to force the compiler to implicitly force unwrap it for you.

Comment: @Wolverine: Agree